# Azure AD Graph API $filter query give 400 error

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm building an application that needs to query identities stored in Azure AD B2C directory.

Building off the Adal4j sample I'm not having any problems until I try and introduce a $filter parameter to the query - so for example this query works fine:

```
URL url = new URL(String.format("https://graph.windows.net/%s/users?api-version=1.6&$orderby=displayName", tenant));
```

However the following query gives me a 400 error, like this:

```
URL url = new URL(String.format("https://graph.windows.net/%s/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=displayName eq 'George'", tenant));
```

Any help gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You must URL-encode the filter value such as:

```
$filter=displayName%20eq%20%27George%27
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! - for others who might be trying to do this through the Azure AD Graph API the following worked for me to retrieve a user by their signInNames : String string5 = "signInNames%2Fany%28x%3Ax%2Fvalue%20eq%20%27joeuser%40gmail.com%27%29";